# techbox.dev:8080 gets redirected from http to https and giving error message

Tags: http, redirect, https, apache2

I installed LAMP on Oracle Virtual Box on windows 8.1. When I try to see the index.html page on firefox:

`http://techbox.dev:8080/index.html` it gets redirected to `https://techbox.dev:8080/index.html`

and get error message:

Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to techbox.dev:8080. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Can someone help me with simple steps (I am NOT technical) to resolve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

**The issue was `.dev`**

**So, I changed:**

`techbox.dev` to `techbox.test`

`*.dev` to `*.test`

`dev-error.log` to `test-error.log`

`dev-access.log` to `test-access.log`